# GDAL GeoTIFF compression from WEBP to JPEG/LZW creating tile-edge artefacts when adding overlays

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, compression, gdaladdo

## Desired Outcome

An *JPEG or LZW* compressed output tiff with overlays, with transparent "no data" zones, and no black "edge artifacts" on the border between "data" and "nodata" areas.

Test data: https://github.com/corn-dog/stack-exchange

### Requirements

1. I need to change the WEBP compression format to either: *JPEG or LZW* (whichever gives the desired outcome).
2. I also I need the alpha channel to render as transparent in the output.tiff, when viewed in Geoserver or QGis etc.
3. Finally, I then need to add overlays to the resultant TIFF.

## Issue

[image]

My current process results in strange black line artifacts on tile edges/borders. I need these removed somehow, or, I need a better process that does not create these artifacts in the first place.

## Background

I have a 4 band (RGBA) WEBP compressed GeoTIFF input file with pixel interleave and 512x512 Blocksizes.

### Current process

To change compression:

```bsh
gdal_translate input.tiff output.tiff \
    -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -mask 4 \
    -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -co ALPHA=YES \
    -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=512 -co BLOCKYSIZE=512
```

To add overlays:

```bsh
gdaladdo out.tiff -r average -ro
```

I am a beginner in GIS.

Comment: Could you share some test data?

Comment: @user30184 just waiting on the okay to share from higher ups, will tag you when i share

Comment: Remember that it does not need to be your data and you can blur or do whatever you want for the pixels in the image, and the smaller the better if the issue can still be reproduced.

Comment: @user30184 here is the test data ! https://github.com/corn-dog/stack-exchange

Comment: @user2856 this works for LZW compression, but I get horrible artifacts if I change to JPEG. My thought was mask is required as JPEG has no alpha channel?